# Cant get Admin Token using cUrl 403 error

Tags: magento2, rest-api, curl

I've managed to get the API Token using Postman however, when I try to get the admin token through a cUrl request it returns a 403 error.

**Postman Post Request:**

- https://localhost/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=admin&password=password

**Magento 2 cUrl Request:**

```
$tokenUrl = "https://localhost/index.php/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token";
$data = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "password");
$dataString = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($tokenUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataString)
));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
return $token;
```

Is this due to missing headers perhaps?

**Update:**

I've confirmed within Swagger the correct url should be https://localhost/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token so I've amended the URL and it still returns a 403. However, adding my admin credentials into the swagger request I can get the API key no problem.

Could it be possible that there is a server permission not allowing rest requests to be made internally on the server?

Comment: URL should be `https://localhost/{MAgento2Root}}/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token`.i.e use magento root directory folder

Comment: Another reason may be `https`. May be localhost does not have SSL. just use `http` in URL.

Comment: I'll give it a try, cheers :)

Comment: It seems to be doing the same, i'm still getting a 403 error after trying it both ways. I presume the magento root is just the first directory? In my case public_html

Comment: Your remaining code is correct. Only issue with URL. and 403 error means forbidden i.e not able to access dir. what is the URL you use to access the website ?

Comment: The actual URL is http://test.com/test/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token i've replaced the site url with test for stack overflow. But i've added in the root directory and proper url in now